# Why do some packages not work in section titles?

Tags: xetex, packages, article, section-titles

Sincere apologies if I am not using the format of this site correctly.

I am using XeLaTeX with article class, and am trying to create commands for abreviations I use often. In two cases, however, commands which work fine in the main text make LaTeX crash when I use them in section titles.

Specifically, it seems that the `\relsize` and `\relscale` commands from the `relsize` package make the compilation crash when used in section titles (`\smaller`, oddly, does not). I encounter the same problem with `\xperiod` from the `xpunctuate` package.

Is there something going on I don't know about?

EDIT : in creating minimum working example, I may know what is wrong, but not how to fix it. Context is creating the styling for centuries in French, which are written in small caps, but small caps don't exist in some bold fonts. So I am trying to create a workaround.

The following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xpunctuate}

\newcommand{\siecle}[1]{\textsc{#1}\textsuperscript{e} siècle}

\newcommand{\boldsiecle}[1]{{\relscale{0.75}\uppercase{#1}}\textsuperscript{e} siècle}

\providecommand{\BC}[0]{\mbox{av. J.-C}\xperiod}

\begin{document}

Nous sommes au \siecle{ii} \BC

Nous sommes au \boldsiecle{ii} \BC

\textbf{Nous sommes au \siecle{ii} \BC}

\textbf{Nous sommes au \boldsiecle{ii} \BC}

\section{La vie au \boldsiecle{ii} \BC} 

Lorem ipsum 

\end{document}
```

[image]

This code crashes (only `hyperref` has been added):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xpunctuate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\siecle}[1]{\textsc{#1}\textsuperscript{e} siècle}

\newcommand{\boldsiecle}[1]{{\relscale{0.75}\uppercase{#1}}\textsuperscript{e} siècle}

\providecommand{\BC}[0]{\mbox{av. J.-C}\xperiod}

\begin{document}

Nous sommes au \siecle{ii} \BC

Nous sommes au \boldsiecle{ii} \BC

\textbf{Nous sommes au \siecle{ii} \BC}

\textbf{Nous sommes au \boldsiecle{ii} \BC}

\section{La vie au \boldsiecle{ii} \BC} 

Lorem ipsum 

\end{document}
```

I imagine hyperref must be clashing with something? What is going on?

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full (but minimal) self contained example. Then it is a **lot** easier to help you. RIght now we have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: Please provide a MWE. The macros provided by `relscale` are robust and worked for me in a simple test, so whatever is happening is due to some code you are withholding.

Comment: The general problem is that the text of each section title get written to the .toc file, and a problem often arises because most commands expand to something other than text.  You can try putting `\protected` in front of the problematic command, but an example would be more helpful.  (And it's a *command* not working in the section title, not a package.)

Comment: google for "fragile command in a moving argument" the examples you give are the classic examples, and prefixing with `\protect` is the general fix.

Comment: That's a standard issue: not all TeX macros are allowed in the argument of `\section` & Co when `hyperref` is loaded. You need `\texorpdfstring`, in your case `\section{La vie au \texorpdfstring{\boldsiecle{ii} \BC}{iie av. J.-C}}` or similar. The first argument is what will be typed in the pdf file, the second argument is the content of the bookmark.

Comment: Try `\section[simple title for TOC]{My complicated title with macros}`